# projectile motion sim - 'illegal start of type' error

Tags: java

I've been given a class called PhysicsVector that deals with vector addition etc, which must be fine as it was written by my professor. My GravField class calculates good estimates of g so I don't think that's the problem. No curls brackets missing, no loops outside methods.

But it still gives 'illegal start of type' error, and points to the particle.getNewVelocity method. And before, when it did compile, the loop never ended and y kept increasing. So there is also a logic error somewhere, but I really can't find it! Anyway, I changed something, and now it's stopped compiling. My main method is here:

```
public class ParticleSim{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);       //User enters initial velocity and size of time interval
    double timeStep = scanner.nextDouble();
    double initialXVelocity = scanner.nextDouble();
    double initialYVelocity = scanner.nextDouble();

    PhysicsVector initialPos = new PhysicsVector();
    initialPos.setVector(0,0);              //Projectile taken to start at origin

    PhysicsVector initialVelocity = new PhysicsVector();
    initialVelocity.setVector(initialXVelocity, initialYVelocity);

    double earthMass = 5.972*Math.pow(10,24);
    double earthRadius = 6371000;

    PhysicsVector g = new PhysicsVector();

    GravField earth = new GravField(earthMass, earthRadius, initialPos);
    g = earth.aDueToGravity(earthMass, earthRadius, initialPos);    //Calculates acceleration due to gravity
                                    //using method in GravField class

    Particle projectile = new Particle(1, initialPos, initialVelocity, timeStep, g);

    double positionY;
    PhysicsVector newPosition= new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector newVelocity = new PhysicsVector();

    do{
        newPosition = projectile.getNewPosition();      //should get the new position of projectile
        g=earth.aDueToGravity(earthMass, earthRadius, newPosition);      //g in new position
        newVelocity = projectile.getNewVelocity();      
        positionY = projectile.positionY();

    }while (positionY>0);
}
```

Then my particle class:

```
public class Particle{

private double mass;
PhysicsVector initialPosition = new PhysicsVector();
PhysicsVector initialVelocity = new PhysicsVector();

public Particle(){
    mass = 1;
    initialPosition.setVector(0,0);
    initialVelocity.setVector(1,1);
}

public Particle(double mass, PhysicsVector a, PhysicsVector b, double timeStep, PhysicsVector aDueToGravity){

    initialPosition = a;
    initialVelocity = b;

    PhysicsVector v = new PhysicsVector();
    v = initialVelocity;                    
    v = v.scale(timeStep, initialVelocity);     //v = initialVelocity *t    

    PhysicsVector a = new PhysicsVector();
    a = a.scale(timeStep, aDueToGravity);       //a = aDueToGravity*t

    initialPosition.increaseBy(v);          //initialPosition = initialPosition + v
    initialVelocity.increaseBy(a);          //initialVelocity = initialVelocity + a 

    initialPosition.print();
    initialVelocity.print();

}

public double positionY(){
    return initialPosition.getY();  //get y component with method in PhysicsVector
}

public PhysicsVector getNewVelocity(){
        //'illegal start of type' error
    return initialVelocity;
}

public PhysicsVector getNewPosition(){
    //Same error here, 'illegal start of type'
    return initialPosition;
}

}
```

GravField class:

```
public class GravField{

public static final double G = 6.674*Math.pow(10,-11);          

private double planetMass;                      
private double planetRadius;                        
PhysicsVector initialPosition = new PhysicsVector();
PhysicsVector distance = new PhysicsVector();
PhysicsVector gravityAcceleration = new PhysicsVector();        


/**
*Default constructor that creates a GravField object with the mass and radius of the earth,
*acting on a projectile starting at x=0, y=0, where the x and y axes are on the surface of the planet
*/
public GravField(){

    double planetMass = 5.972*Math.pow(10,24);
    double planetRadius = 6371000;

}

/** 
*Constructor that creates a GravField object
*@param planetMass Mass of the planet whose field is to be calculated
*@param planetRadius Radius of the planet
*@param projectileX initial x co-ordinate of a projectile moving in the planet's gravitational field
*@param projectileY initial y co-ordinate of the projectile
*/ 
public GravField(double mass, double radius, PhysicsVector initialPos){

    planetMass = mass;
    planetRadius = radius;
    initialPosition = initialPos;

}


//Calculates the acceleration due to the gravitational field of the object
public PhysicsVector aDueToGravity(double planetMass, double planetRadius, PhysicsVector initialPosition){
    double y = planetRadius;
    double x = 0;
    distance.setVector(x,y);
    initialPosition.increaseBy(distance);

    double initialX = initialPosition.getX();
    double initialY = initialPosition.getY();
    double distance = Math.sqrt((initialX)*(initialX)+initialY*initialY);

    double a = (-1*G*planetMass*initialX)/(distance*distance*distance); 
    double b = (-1*G*planetMass*(initialY))/(distance*distance*distance);
    gravityAcceleration.setVector(a,b);
    System.out.println("printing g");
    gravityAcceleration.print();
    return gravityAcceleration;
}

public double magnitude(){

    return gravityAcceleration.magnitude(); 

}

public double componentX(){

    return gravityAcceleration.getX();                  
}

public double componentY(){

    return gravityAcceleration.getY();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have PhysicsVector class in that same package ? Can you share the code for PhysicsVector. May be the constructor is private or you need to pass some values to it.

Comment: @StackFlowed Yes. Previous versions using PhysicsVectors and PhysicsVector methods have compiled.

Comment: Looking at your code closely you don't need those lines if you remove it your code should work fine. In fact you just need return initialVelocity; & return initialPosition; FYI your getNewPosition has compile errors as you create newVelocity but use newPosition.

Comment: Is your PhysicsVector declared public?

Comment: You're missing a closing brace for the Particle class.

Comment: @BrianReindel Oops, it's not missing in the actual code, didn't copy it in. My mistake.

Comment: @StackFlowed Yes, I did use newVelocity. Oops. Changing it didn't help though, and nor did doing return initialPosition or return initialVelocity and deleting all the other bits.

Comment: You need to post all your code. It's hard to piece together what's happening without it.

Comment: @JoshChappelle I can't post the PhysicsVector class, it's way too long! But I can promise that's not the problem . I'll add my GravField class to the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was created a PhysicsVector class :

```
public class PhysicsVector {
    double y;
    public void setVector(int i, int i1) {
    }

    public PhysicsVector scale(double timeStep, PhysicsVector initialVelocity) {
        return initialVelocity;
    }

    public void increaseBy(PhysicsVector a) {
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void print() {
    }
}
```

And my particle class looked like :

```
public class Particle{
    private double mass;
    private PhysicsVector initialPosition = new PhysicsVector();
    private PhysicsVector initialVelocity = new PhysicsVector();

    public Particle(){
        mass = 1;
        initialPosition.setVector(0,0);
        initialVelocity.setVector(1,1);
    }

    public Particle(double mass, PhysicsVector a, PhysicsVector b, double timeStep, PhysicsVector aDueToGravity){
        initialPosition = a;
        initialVelocity = b;

        PhysicsVector v = new PhysicsVector();
        v = initialVelocity;
        v = v.scale(timeStep, initialVelocity);     //v = initialVelocity *t

        PhysicsVector a = new PhysicsVector();
        a = a.scale(timeStep, aDueToGravity);       //a = aDueToGravity*t

        initialPosition.increaseBy(v);          //initialPosition = initialPosition + v
        initialVelocity.increaseBy(a);          //initialVelocity = initialVelocity + a

        initialPosition.print();
        initialVelocity.print();
    }

    public double positionY(){
        return initialPosition.getY();  //get y component with method in PhysicsVector
    }

    public PhysicsVector getNewVelocity(){
        return initialVelocity;
    }

    public PhysicsVector getNewPosition(){
        return initialPosition;
    }
}
```

The only error / warning I got was `variable 'a' is already defined in scope`.
Im sure you are missing some information on your question or the code in question is different for the one you have.

Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your problem. This will help you understand and solve your problem better

Comment: Very good idea!!! Helped me find the mistake! Thanks, there was a lot of code to wade through.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to close the question out with marking this as a correct answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

In your second Particle constructor there is a duplicate local variable "a". You are passing in a PhysicsVector that you have named "a" and you are declaring another PhysicsVector variable named "a".

That's the only problem I am seeing, given that I do not have the PhysicsVector class. Try fixing that and see if that helps.

Comment: Still doesn't compile, but that would have caused problems down the line! Thanks.

Comment: Basically, I'm after a way to use the calculated values of position and velocity in the main method. I can't get them directly from the constructor, which is why I tried using a separate method to get the position and one for velocity. Is there an easier way?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your program is trying to do so I can't really answer that. I will say that your code compiles fine for me. However I had to create my own version of PhysicsVector.